# ¿Cómo obtengo una lista de valores de una Sheet en base a una condición?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheets

Necesito Filtrar la lista de Correos de acuerdo al Área que pertenece el Cumpleañero:

*Si la fecha de hoy es igual a la fecha en la sheet  obtiene todos los correos que son del área a la que pertenece esa persona:

*¿Cómo filtro la lista de correos de la Sheet por cada una de las 3 áreas?

- Necesito guardar esos correos en variables independientes para poder usarlos después.
- Si se agregan más registros después con áreas nuevas, hacer lo mismo de manera automática.

```
function sendEmail () {
    var sps       = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//llamamos al objeto global "SpreadsheetApp" y le Pasámos el parámetro "getActive" para que trabaje con la spreadsheet actual
    var sheetName = 'database';//Asignamos un nombre a la sheet que contiene la información o datos
    var sheet     = sps.getSheetByName(sheetName);//accedemos a la sheet por medio del nombre
    var data      = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();//Vamos a obtener los valores y almacenarlos en el arreglo "data"

    /* Crear el arreglo de objetos que contendra todos los registros */
    var array_object = [];

    for (var i= 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row             = data[i];
      var name            = row[0]
      var mail            = row[1];
      var date            = row[2]+'/'+row[3];
      var workPosition    = row[4];
      var area            = row[5];

      var info = new Object (); 
      {
        info.NAME       = name;
        info.EMAIL      = mail;
        info.BIRTHDATE  = date.toUpperCase();
        info.JOB        = workPosition;
        info.AREA       = area;
     }

/* Inserta la "info" en el "array_object" */
    array_object.push(info);
    }

/* El constructor crea un objeto Date con la hora y fecha de hoy según la hora local */
    var currentDate = new Date();

  /* Construye un arreglo para obtener el nombre de los meses */
    var month     = new Array();
        month[0]  = "ENERO";
        month[1]  = "FEBRERO";
        month[2]  = "MARZO";
        month[3]  = "ABRIL";
        month[4]  = "MAYO";
        month[5]  = "JUNIO";
        month[6]  = "JULIO";
        month[7]  = "AGOSTO";
        month[8]  = "SEPTIEMBRE";
        month[9]  = "OCTUBRE";
        month[10] = "NOVIEMBRE";
        month[11] = "DICIEMBRE";

    var nameMonth = month[currentDate.getMonth()];

    /* Define la fecha actual */
    var month   = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;//Devuelve el mes (de 0-11) por eso el +1
    var day     = currentDate.getUTCDate();//devuelve el día del mes (de 1 a 31) del objeto de fecha, de acuerdo con la hora universal

/* Define la variable "today" con el dia y el mes actual */
    var today   = day + "/" + nameMonth;

    Logger.log(today);

/* Define el arreglo "congratulation" con los datos de los cumpleañeros */   
    var congratulation = [];

/* Acceder a las propiedades del "array_object" por medio de un ciclo For */
      for (var x = 0; x < array_object.length; x++) {
          if ( today == array_object[x].BIRTHDATE ) {
                congratulation.push('Hoy es Cumpleaños de: ' + '\n'
                                   + 'Nombre: ' +array_object[x].NAME +'\n'
                                   + 'Fecha de Nacimiento: '+array_object[x].BIRTHDATE +'\n'
                                   + 'Puesto: '+array_object[x].JOB +'\n'
                                   + 'Área: '+array_object[x].AREA +'\n'
                                   + 'Correo: '+array_object[x].EMAIL +'\n');
                                }

       }   

 /* Logger.log(congratulation);

[Hoy es Cumpleaños de: 
Nombre: Carlos Alberto
Fecha de Nacimiento: 23/NOVIEMBRE
Puesto: DIRECTOR
Área: DIRECCION
Correo: directorgraltest@gmail.com
, Hoy es Cumpleaños de: 
Nombre: Elizabeth
Fecha de Nacimiento: 23/NOVIEMBRE
Puesto: SEGURIDAD INTERNA
Área: PROSEGUR
Correo: testsendmail307@gmail.com
, Hoy es Cumpleaños de: 
Nombre: Édgar
Fecha de Nacimiento: 23/NOVIEMBRE
Puesto: CONTADOR B
Área: CONTABILIDAD
Correo: contatestsendmail307@gmail.com

*/

}
```

la sheet es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el método [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de JavaScript con una función anónima como parámetro en la cual se evalúe la condición.

A continuación un ejemplo sencillo de cómo usarlo en una secuencia de comandos (script) vinculada a una hoja de cálculo de Google.

Para fines de ejemplo, se indica como referencia `A:B`. La condición es que el que los valores de la columna B  deben ser iguales al parámetro `area`.

```
function miFiltro(area) {
  var referencia = "A:B";
  var valores = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(referencia).getValues();
  var columna = 1; // Indice base 0;
  var salida = valores.filter(function(valor){
    return valor[columna] == area;
  });
  return salida;
}
```

Comment: Hola Rubén, no me quedo muy clara la respuesta, apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar, usaré el método filter que mencionas, Gracias por responder